# Transfer pictures via iCloud to new Mac

Tags: icloud

I had my Mac stolen last week. I now have a new one and would like all the photos I had backed up on iCloud on my new Mac. How do I do this?

Comment: How did you back up photos from a Mac into iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

If the photos were in **Photo Stream**, then you can go to **System Preferences** → **iCloud**, log in and check the box for **Photos**. Then, open iPhoto/Aperture and let it download the photos.

If the photos were added to iCloud by a specific app, go to **System Preferences** → **iCloud**, log in and check the box for **Documents & Data**, then open the app that you used to back up the photos.

If the photos were manually backed up to the Mobile Documents folder, go to **System Preferences** → **iCloud**, log in and check the box for **Documents & Data**, then wait for your files to sync.